# Handling a very big matrix of 0s and 1s

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have a huge matrix (20000x20000) obtained using [CPR toolbox](http://tocsy.pik-potsdam.de/CRPtoolbox/) in matlab. When I tried to write this natrix to a text file from matlab workspace, using `dlmwrite` it took a very long time  and so I had aborted the process.

1. What is the easy way of writing this to a text file? The entire matrix consists of 0s and 1s only i.e. each entry in a matrix is either 1 or 0. I am mentioning this because I believe there has to be an easy way of writing 0s and 1s.
2. The entire matrix has to be plotted as black(1) and white(0) dot (kinda like chess board but with more points based on matrix ). I usually plot figures using `pgfplot` of latex. In this case(as the dataset is huge) is it advisable to use latex? If not, what plotting tool can handle such a huge dataset easily?

A typical recurrence plot will look like this:
[image]

Comment: for plotting use `spy(mymatrix)`

Comment: for writing specify Integer as your data type.

Comment: Do you really need to save the matrix to a text file? Couldn't you save it using `.mat` format?

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro: The problem is that Latex can not read .mat files.

Comment: So I assume you are aiming to include these figures in a document of some sort. If you use A4 paper at 600dpi, you would be able to fit 4961 X 7016 pixels on a single sheet. It's not really meaningful to try and fit four figures at 20000 by 20000 each on one sheet. Use other tools from Matlab to output your figures e.g. in pdf format and include them in your LaTeX document. Take a look at [`print`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) for example.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Are the matrices sparse at all?

Comment: @mikkola: The figures are included for representation purpose only. Anyway, I'll try that pdf option.

Comment: @edwinksl: No. I'll convert them in matlab.

Comment: if you save in text file, and you just use ASCII (8bits per char) with a single space between each char, this would take 20000*20000*2, bytes or 0.8 Gb per matrix. You sure this is what you want? It looks liek a terrible idea

Comment: You can't plot that much of data with TeX. Don't bother.